# Are there Trojan or Hilda asteroids locked in Earth's orbit?

Tags: astrophysics

Jupiter has many [Trojan asteroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_Trojan) located at Lagrangian points L4 and L5 and [Hilda asteroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilda_family) dispersed between points L3, L4, and L5.

Does the Earth have similar asteroids?  If so, how many?

Comment: I don't see the physics in this, but I'm almost positive it would be a perfect fit on [astronomy.SE]. Since it's a beta site, I can't (shouldn't) migrate the question, but I'd suggest that you go re-ask it there (check and see if it's already been asked, though).

Comment: The first Earth Trojan was announced a few months ago:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_TK7
Its orbital motion is still not fully understood, and may be chaotic.